# How do I exit the ChromeDriver (via Python Selenium) once there are no more pages left on Google Image Search?

Tags: python, selenium

On Python (via **Selenium library**), I am attempting to scrape images from Google Images. All seems well, but if I input a high number of images (e.g. 1500), then the program will just keep looking for images and the webdriver will keep going on (see output below), even though the webdriver has reached the end of the page.

**Output:**

```
Found: 32 search results. Extracting links from 20:32
Found: 19 image links, looking for more ...
Found: 32 search results. Extracting links from 32:32
Found: 19 image links, looking for more ...
```

Here is my Python code for fetching image URL's...

```
def fetch_image_urls(query: str, max_links_to_fetch: int, wd: webdriver, sleep_between_interactions: int = 1):
    def scroll_to_end(wd):
        wd.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        time.sleep(sleep_between_interactions)

    search_url = "https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&site=&tbm=isch&source=hp&q={q}&oq={q}&gs_l=img"

    wd.get(search_url.format(q=query))

    image_urls = set()
    image_count = 0
    results_start = 0
    while image_count < max_links_to_fetch:

        scroll_to_end(wd)

        thumbnail_results = wd.find_elements_by_css_selector("img.Q4LuWd")
        number_results = len(thumbnail_results)

        print(f"Found: {number_results} search results. Extracting links from {results_start}:{number_results}")

        for img in thumbnail_results[results_start:number_results]:
            try:
                img.click()
                time.sleep(sleep_between_interactions)
            except Exception:
                continue

                # extract image urls
            actual_images = wd.find_elements_by_css_selector('img.n3VNCb')
            for actual_image in actual_images:
                if actual_image.get_attribute('src') and 'http' in actual_image.get_attribute('src'):
                    image_urls.add(actual_image.get_attribute('src'))

            image_count = len(image_urls)

            if len(image_urls) >= max_links_to_fetch:
                print(f"Found: {len(image_urls)} image links, done!")
                break
        else:
            print("Found:", len(image_urls), "image links, looking for more ...")
            time.sleep(30)
            # return
            load_more_button = wd.find_element_by_css_selector(".mye4qd")
            if load_more_button:
                wd.execute_script("document.querySelector('.mye4qd').click();")

        results_start = len(thumbnail_results)

    return image_urls
```

I've tried using `wd.close()` after the if load_more_button statement towards the end of the method, and I've tried to make another `while` loop after `while image_count < max_links_to_fetch`, but instead of using `image_count`, I've used `number_results`.

Comment: You are never getting to max so it's just continuing...  You should break if the load more button is not found... (or if you find the "there are no more results" text...)

Comment: @pcalkins - It works now. Thank you